# javascript - append text after URL element

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to append something to a URL using javascript? and to remove prefixes?

e.g. "http://www.google.com/" into "google.com.local/"

Comment: You can use the `window.location` object to override parts of the url, but I think, this would cause a reload.

Answer (score 0):

The `concat()` method is used to join two or more strings.

This method does not change the existing strings, but returns a new string containing the text of the joined strings. In your case:

```
var mystring = concat("http://www.google.com",".local");
```

And for removing parts from string - use `split()` method to split a string into an array of substrings, and returns the new array.

Tip: If an empty string ("") is used as the separator, the string is split between each character.

Note: The `split()` method also does not change the original string.

Answer (score 0):

You can change URL by using window-object, e.g.:

```
window.location.href = url + '/' + ID
```

Comment: Using my example would this turn www.google.com into www.google.com/ID ?

Comment: Well, I didn't pay attention on how exactly you want to manipulate your URL. I just wanted to give you an example how to access the current URL and how to append some random text, sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
var url = "http://www.google.com/";
url.replace(/^(https?:\/\/)?(\w+\.)?(\w+\.\w+)/, "$3.local");
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/qn5h5/

Answer (score -1):

The javascript location object http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_location.asp gives you access to url's hostname path etc. I don't exactly know what you are looking for, but this can help.