# Javascript/Jquery Syntax for adding something in between a URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

folks!

I would like to add something like "_something_more" to a background-image URL.

For e.g. I got "url(random_folder/random_image.jpg)"

And I need a generated URL string like: "url(random_folder/random_image_something_more.jpg)"

Tried it with the split() and concat() method but didn't realy get it to work...

I've read about this in [this already existing thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10979543/javascript-append-text-after-url-element) but it doesn't cover the whole problem quiet well enough for me to understand and isn't really the same issue.

I need this to replace the background-image URLs from high resolution images to lower resolution images for mobile content.

In hope for your wisdom and help: A happy Wednesday to everybody!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var background = $('body').css('background-image');
var start = background.substr(0, background.lastIndexOf('.'));
var end = background.substr(background.lastIndexOf('.'));
$('body').css('background-image', start + '_something_more' + end);
```